# Neo4j failing to build on fresh Ubuntu 18 Desktop

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I've installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04.2 Desktop AMDx64 in a VBox virtual machine (same problem happens on WSL and none VM installation of ubuntu)
-Installed git, maven, openjdk-8-jdk
-changed java version to 1.8.0_222 (Neo4j doesn't seem to fully support higher JDK yet?) using update-alternatives
-cd into the directory and `mvn clean install`

However, it fails to compile and gives me this error:

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time:  30.098 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-05T06:53:55Z
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:licensing-maven-plugin:1.7.7:check (list-all-licenses) on project neo4j-annotation-processors: Could not read licensing requirements file: licensing/licensing-requirements-base.xml: Cannot construct org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.CoalescedLicense as it does not have a no-args constructor : Cannot construct org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.CoalescedLicense as it does not have a no-args constructor
>   [ERROR] ---- Debugging information ----
>   [ERROR] message             : Cannot construct org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.CoalescedLicense as it does not have a no-args constructor
>   [ERROR] cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
>   [ERROR] cause-message       : Cannot construct org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.CoalescedLicense as it does not have a no-args constructor
>   [ERROR] class               : org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.CoalescedLicense
>   [ERROR] required-type       : org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.CoalescedLicense
>   [ERROR] converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
>   [ERROR] path                : /licensing-requirements/coalesced-licenses/license
>   [ERROR] line number         : 81
>   [ERROR] class[1]            : java.util.HashSet
>   [ERROR] converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
>   [ERROR] class[2]            : org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.model.LicensingRequirements
>   [ERROR] version             : null
>   [ERROR] -------------------------------
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>   [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :neo4j-annotation-processors

Since this is just a sanity check before editing the code there shouldn't be any problems compiling the original source code.
Anyone could possibly locate what went wrong even after following exact instructions from the Neo4j git repo?
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: java version 1.8.0_222

Comment: Please delete the .m2 directory and run mvn clean install again

Comment: Still gives the same error on all environments